# Retain the leading zero on conversion from String to Double

Tags: java

I have the below java code snippet:

```
String str = "0123";
Double dbl = Double.valueOf(str);
```

The value of dbl become `123.0`

But I want to get the value as `0123.0`

Is there any way to preserve the leading zero in java?

Comment: You can't have leading zeros on doubles.

Comment: Not possible as you want it, not in double

Comment: what do you pretend keeping theses zeroes?

Comment: @LuisGonzález This is actually related to encryption. When I am encrypting few values say 123 the encrypted value will come as 0987; and I want to convert this to Double.

Two things here:
1. I can encrypt only string values, that's why I am not encrypting it using the double value as such.
2. The encryption which I am using will preserve the number of digit after encryption

Comment: @PraveenPMoolekandathil why do you need convert to Double? you need to do some operation ?

Comment: @LuisGonzález I want to store the encrypted value into database and in database the field type is double.
And whenever the value fetched from database that will be decrypted; the result will be wrong if one digit missed even if it is a leading zero . So each and every digit is important even if it's a leading zero.